# How to override LiveData toString in Android

Tags: android, android-room, android-livedata

Im playing around with android as Im trying to learn M-V-VM with androids Room. I have Created a structure as follows:

Person.class, PersonDao.class, PersonDatabase.class, DatabaseRepository.class, PersonViewModel.class, MainActivity.class

ActivityMain.class

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private EditText age;
private EditText name;
Person person;
private PersonViewModel personViewModel;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    name = findViewById(R.id.name);
    age = findViewById(R.id.age);
    personViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(PersonViewModel.class);
}

public void addPerson(View view){
    int sAge = Integer.parseInt(age.getText().toString());
    String sName = name.getText().toString();
    person = new Person(sName, sAge);
    System.out.println(person.toString());
    personViewModel.insert(person);
    System.out.println(personViewModel.getmAllPeople());
  }
}
```

Is there a spot I can @Override a toString() method (perhaps in the Dao) so when I  print to system out I don't get:

I/System.out: android.arch.lifecycle.ComputableLiveData$1@7638ae0 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, sorry -- you are not creating that object. Room is.

Answer (score 0):

You can Override "toString" method in your Person.class
(Use Ctrl+O for simplicity)